# Do action before spring context created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I execute the action, before Spring context created? I found only one solution that more or less can satisfy me, it is listening `ApplicationStartingEvent` but I don't know how correctly do it because Spring doesn't see listener bean because context not created yet. So maybe someone knows ways how to catch `ApplicationStartingEvent` or maybe another better solution to do it.

Comment: What is your use case? Have you tried [EnvironmentPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/env/EnvironmentPostProcessor.html)?

Comment: What particular action do you need? There are a lot of options (BPP's,BFP's,PostConstruct,InitializingBeans, etc ...) You just need to pick one that suits you better.

Comment: @aleshka-batman, BPP's, BFP's,PostConstruct, all these variants not suit for me. I should start Zookeeper, and some bean will use this Zookeeper in this PostConstruct or constructor, and this bean(that use Zookeeper) Spring decided to create before component that starts my Zookeeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface ApplicationContextInitializer could suffice for your requirement.

Read [ApplicationContextInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html) documentation

Implementing ApplicationContextInitializer allows you to do additional tasks/initializations before persistent bean definition is loaded (i.e. your application-context.xml). One such use is, when you want to select profiles before you will load definitions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it.